# How to reduce timeout for Connection.Open in ODP.NET

Tags: oracle11g, odp.net

I was doing a cable-pull test for my C# Oracle 11g ODP.NET4 application.  Once I pull the cable and try to connect to Oracle, the Connection.Open() method waits about 15 seconds before returning with error "Connection request timed out".

I would like to see this 15 seconds reduced to 5, or 3 even.

I assumed that the connection string parameter "Connection Timeout" would solve this but it did not.  I set it to 3 and the Open still takes 15 seconds.  After a bit of reading it turns out that parameter has more to do with pooling and may not apply here.

Is there a way to reduce the time it takes for the Open command to return with an error?

Thanks!

Comment: The 15 seconds is the TCP timeout: http://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows  Not sure what other effects it has if you lower those values

Answer (score 0):

You should look into FAN and FCF.